# Menu is visible only if use hamburger

Tags: html, css

**When I'm on the site the menu is hidden.** 
**Then when I resize the page and use the hamburger the menu is showing normally.**
 When I resize the page back the menu is still visible. 
After refreshing site the problem is repeating.

**U see the problem on my demo page:**

**I'll be really glad if you help me with this.**

### Thanks.

---

**Code:**

```css
body {
  min-height: 100%;
}


/* HEADER */

#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 1000px;
  right: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.backgroundheader {
  top: 0 !important;
  position: relative !important;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #333;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  background-image: url("images/bamboo.png"), url("images/bamboo2.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 560px, 195px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  background-position: top right, top left
}

.logo {
  left: 0 !important;
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  background-color: #AB2732;
  float: left !important
}


/* HEADER */


/* MENU */

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 220%;
  font-family: menu
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 23px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111111;
}

.vyber {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #AB2732;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 410px;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation-name: vysunuti;
  animation-duration: 0.8s;
  box-shadow: inset -0px 0 40px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  margin-bottom: 200px;
}

.hamburger {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.hamburger-box {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1246px) {
  ul {
    top: 345px;
    z-index: 99
  }
  ul li {
    ;
    background-color: #333;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%
  }
  .hamburger {
    visibility: visible
  }
  .hamburger-box {
    -webkit-animation: hamburger 0.5s ease-in-out;
    animation: hamburger 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes hamburger {
  from {
    opacity: 0
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@font-face {
  font-family: menu;
  src: url("fonty/menu.otf");
}


/* MENU */


/* MENU */
```

```html
<div class="nav" id="header">
  <div class="backgroundheader">
    <div class="logo"></div>
    <div class="simple-ss"></div>

    <div id="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button style="right: 0 !important; position: absolute;margin-right: 30px;margin-top: 350px;z-index: 10" class="hamburger hamburger--spring navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" type="button">
                            <span class="hamburger-box">
                                <span class="hamburger-inner"></span>
                            </span>
                        </button>

        <div class="vyber">
          <div class=" collapse " id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <ul>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">O nás</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Restaurace</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Running sushi</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#">Fotogalerie</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For me it is working. If I resize the page and make it smaller, the hamburger appears. When I resize it to normal size back, it disappears.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. The code you posted doesn't even show the hamburger.

Comment: But I don't know how to show that menu bigger than 1246px (size when hamburger is showing). Hamburger is without problem. Problem is that menu is not visible on bigger screens. Sorry if I explained it bad. @D.Simon

Comment: Do you get the expected result after declaring the following styles? `.collapse {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1246px) {

    .collapse {
    display: none;
    }
    
}`

Comment: Okay. You were right. But I had to add `!important` tag after `.collapse { display: block; }`. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hamburger is not your problem.

Here is pseudo code how your website works now:

### YOUR PSEUDO CODE

```
var showMenu = false;
var showButton = false;

if 1246px > windowWidth 
    showButton = true;

if buttonIsClicked == true
    showMenu = !showMenu;
        (if it is true it will set to false)
        (if it is false it will set to true)
```

### PROBLEM

So you need to show your menu when a user gets on the website.
When the `windowWidth` is smaller then the `1246px` you stop showing the menu and shows the button.
Now when the user disables the menu and make the `windowWidth` bigger than `1246px` you need to enable the menu again. this will look like this in pseudo code.

### GOOD PSEUDO CODE

```
var showMenu = true;
var showButton = false;

if 1246px > windowWidth 
    showButton = true;
    showMenu = false;

if 1246px < windowWidth
    showMenu = true;

if buttonIsClicked == true
    showMenu = !showMenu;
```

With this knowledge you should be able to solve your css